# Date being identified sometimes as string, sometimes as date

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have a script that uploads a `Date / Time` to Datastore. Everything worked perfectly for a while, but after some time I noticed the following:

[image]

I decided to investigate this issue, using the following query:

`SELECT DISTINCT data_subida FROM mynamespace ORDER BY data_subida DESC`

The query above got me the following results:

[image]

It shows me that it stopped sending data on January 10th, but I am sure I am sending more data, so I scrolled down and found the following:

[image]

At some point, Datastore stopped storing my date as a `Date / Time` and started storing it as a `String`. But, if I open the entity to visualize its data, I get the following result:

[image]

So, is this a common issue? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to tell Datastore to `CAST` or `CONVERT` my field before ordering? Or at least force it to query only the ones interpreted as `Date / Time` or as `String`. I need to use this timestamp as a watermark in a ETL process, and without proper ordering I will duplicate the data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see in the examples(at google doc site) that they use  com.google.cloud.Timestamp   You should probably use that.

Comment: @rickz apparently there is no such thing for PHP. The datastore is unusable with such issue...

Comment: Sorry, I use Java.  For PHP, I see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/datastore/api/src/functions/concepts.php      and in there they use something named   DateTime